# Fabric JS Groups not resizing

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I hope you can help. I'm having some trouble programmatically resizing a Group of Fabric JS objects. I add the objects to the canvas using canvas.add(object) and then add them to the group. However when trying to resize the objects as a group, the usual setHeight(), scale() and scaleToWidth/Height() methods seem to have no effect.

My code is in several places, but the essence is:

```
var obj = ........ // I Get my obj from an SVG path
var objectGroup = new fabric.Group();
canvas.clipTo = function(ctx) {
    obj.render(ctx);
}
objectGroup.add(obj);
```

I also tried `objectGroup.addWithUpdate(obj);`

Then, after adding more objects to the group; in my resize event, I work out the scale I need and do:

```
objectGroup.scaleToWidth(newX);
objectGroup.scaleToHeight(newY);
objectGroup.setCoords();
canvas.renderAll();
```

Am I missing something?? Do I have to add my obj to the canvas as well as rendering it inside the clipTo function?

Thanks in advance :)